# Are there any shortcut key to insert a definition of a function?

Tags: c++, ide, clion, jetbrains-ide

I use the Jetbrain's IDE Clion.

I want to insert a definition of a function whose forward declaration is already in header file to source file

For example,

I write foo.h file like this.

```
namespace sample{
  class Foo{
    void bar();
  };
}
```

When I use the shortcut, I want to insert this to foo.cpp.

```
sample::Foo:bar(){}
```

Do you have any good suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to implement your method :

```
// Definition of our method
void sample::Foo::bar()
{
    // .....
}
```

***Implement required methods :***

On the Code menu, click Implement methods (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>). Alternatively, you can right-click anywhere in the class file, then click Generate (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>), and select Implement methods.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Of course, I know I need the definition fo my method. Currently, I search a way to auto-insert.

Comment: Sorry to reply late.
Thank you, it is just my wanted function!